# How to print data in variable c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print 'count' as it holds my results but i can't seem to manage.Basically i need to print the results from this set of code. Any Suggestions ? Console.WriteLine("Count: ", count); is telling me that count does not exist in the current context. I've tried changing the count method to public int but still the same.Am i trying to print in the wrong position or do i need to create a variable to declare count ?

```
private int Test(Char[,] data, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        if(data[x, y] == '*')
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

private int GetCount(Char[,] data, int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;
    count += Test(data, -1, -1);
    count += Test(data, 1, 1);
    count += Test(data, -1, 1);
    count += Test(data, 1, -1);
    count += Test(data, 0, -1);
    count += Test(data, 0, 1);
    count += Test(data, 1, 0);
    count += Test(data, -1, 0);
    return count;                         
}

try
{
    var rows = int.Parse(inputSize[0]);
    var cols = int.Parse(inputSize[1]);

    Char[,] Template = new Char[rows, cols];

    foreach( var rowId in Enumerable.Range(0, rows))
    {
        var inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        if (inputValue.Length == cols)
        {
            if (inputValue.All(x => x == '*' || x == '.'))
            {
                // convert string to array.
                char[] array1 = inputValue.ToCharArray();

                // Loop through array.
                for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                {
                    char inputChar = array1[i];
                    // Get character from array.
                    Template[rowId, i] = inputChar;                                   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Input value '{inputValue}' has unaccaptable characters");
            }
        }
        else
        {
             Console.WriteLine($"Value length of '{inputValue}' does not match of column size {cols}");
        }  
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.WriteLine("Count: ", count); //This line is not working
}
```

Comment: I think you have missed out some code? What does the `Test` method do?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(count);`

Comment: i have added the test method to question

Comment: Please read the [mcve] page. Then [edit] the question to show a minimal example that shows the problem. (Hint: where is the `Main` method?)

Comment: added more code

Comment: looks like you wrote the code outside of any method which is illegal in C# - this may seem stupid at first, but makes sense. You need `public static void Main(string[] args)` method in any class to even start the program. Start with a program that runs at all, then try to add your code

Comment: i know, i have public static void obviously just didnt show it.

Comment: A [mcve] should include enough code that we can understand and repeat the problem without having to guess which pieces you have omitted. Based on the wording in the question, your response to comments and the added code, it is not obvious that you had written a `Main` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the console, just write

```
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", count);
```

`Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(count)); // this may also work, not sure though.`

Hope this is the type of answer you were looking for!

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine()` method has an overload that takes an int, so you don't need the `Convert.ToString` method in your second example - just `Console.WriteLine(count);`

Comment: Ah thanks for the correction, see I wasn't super sure if it was only able to accept strings or not.

Comment: You can look it up online: [Console.WriteLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I've tried these, but if i do it in the method it tells me unreachable code. And if i do it outside the method it tells me the name 'count' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What you may be able to do is since you are returning count, you can just call the function inside the Console.WriteLine() like: `Console.WriteLine(GetCount(x,y,z,a);`

Can't say that will work for sure, but it seems to be worth trying.

Comment: does not exist in current context also.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is an `Object`, and object has a function called `ToString()`.
You can just concatinate strings however you want:

```
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString()); // works with any object, some may give nonsense though.
Console.WriteLine("The value of count is " + count.ToString()); // concatination
Console.WriteLine(count); // WriteLine has an overload for integer
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString("N2")); // up to two decimal places, but will use the local culture.
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString("N2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // The same, but with invariant culture
Console.WriteLine("Count is {0}", count); // format string
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Count is {0}", count)); // built string from format string before passing to console.writeline
```

There are probably more way to display an integer to console.

[More info on int.ToString() and Format strings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring)

Comment: These are all good but my problem is that its not declared out of the method GetCount and i need to declare it but im not sure how since i need it to be equal to the result from the GetCount method.

Comment: @JulianZahra i don't understand your question. You're not calling your GetCount method anywhere.